# CZMQ "zsocket_new" router creation always NULL?

Tags: c, zeromq

I'm trying to create a C-ZeroMQ router, but it seems that there is a problem with the way I'm making it. My router seems to be initialized to null, which causes the rest of my client code to fail. Any tips on why would be much appreciated.

My program is based off the CZMQ File Transfer Model 3 code, but when I run it on my system I find that the zsocket_new function to create "router" doesn't seem to be properly creating "router," so when I assert(router) my program crashes.

I originally discovered this when my program started crashing at the zsocket_set_hwm() function a few lines later. I investigated by checking my logs and discovered that my program stopped before managing complete "assert router":

```
 : zmq: attempting to open target file
 : zmq: asserting ctx...
 : zmq: asserted ctx...
 : zmq: router value = 6
 : zmq: created router
 : zmq: asserting router......
```

Next I loaded the program in GDB and found that router keeps initialized as 0x0.

```
(gdb) print ctx
$1 = <optimized out>
(gdb) print router
$2 = (void *) 0x0
(gdb) print complete_address
$3 = 0x7fffe80009a0 "tcp://127.0.0.1:6000"
```

It seems like there's an issue declaring router, but what could possibly be going wrong with my code? I'm using a corresponding client program which reports no problems at all (here's a bit of it):

```
zctx_t *ctx = zctx_new ();
void *dealer = zsocket_new (ctx, ZMQ_DEALER);

fprintf(fp_srv_log, "%s : %s\n", time_str, "ZMQ client thread launched successfully");

zsocket_bind (dealer, "tcp://*:6000");

fprintf(fp_srv_log, "%s : %s\n", time_str, "client: bound tcp://*:6000");
```

And here's the offending code, the server:

```
int send_file( void *args, zctx_t *ctx, void *pipe )
{
   time_t raw_time;
   struct tm* timeinfo;

   struct arg_struct *input = (struct arg_struct *)args;
   const char *fp = input->file_name;

   time( &raw_time );
   timeinfo = localtime( &raw_time );
   char * time_str = asctime( timeinfo );
   char * complete_address = "tcp://127.0.0.1:6000";
   FILE *fp_clnt_log = fopen( "/var/log/myLog.log", "w" ); 

   int chunkNum = 0;
   fprintf( fp_clnt_log, "%s : zmq: attempting to open target file \n", time_str );
   FILE *file_to_xfer = fopen( fp, "r" );
   assert( file_to_xfer );

   time_str = asctime( timeinfo );

   fprintf( fp_clnt_log, "%s : zmq: asserting ctx...\n", time_str );
   assert( ctx );
   fprintf( fp_clnt_log, "%s : zmq: asserted ctx...\n", time_str );
   fprintf( fp_clnt_log, "%s : zmq: router value = %d\n", time_str, ZMQ_ROUTER );
   void *router = zsocket_new (ctx, ZMQ_ROUTER);
   fprintf( fp_clnt_log, "%s : zmq: created router\n", time_str );
   fprintf( fp_clnt_log, "%s : zmq: asserting router......\n", time_str );
   assert( router );
   fprintf( fp_clnt_log, "%s : zmq: asserted router successfully.\n", time_str );

   //two parts per msg so HWM is size PIPELINE * 2
   zsocket_set_hwm (router, PIPELINE * 2);
   fprintf( fp_clnt_log, "%s : zmq: set hwm complete\n", time_str );

   fprintf( fp_clnt_log, "%s : zmq: attempting to connect to %s\n", time_str, complete_address );
   if( 0 == zsocket_connect (router, complete_address ) )
   {
       fprintf( fp_clnt_log, "%s : zmq: connected to %s\n", time_str, complete_address );
   }
   else
   {
       fprintf( fp_clnt_log, "%s : zmq: failed to connect to %s\n", time_str, complete_address );
   }
   while (true)
   {
       time( &raw_time );
   timeinfo = localtime( &raw_time );
   time_str = asctime( timeinfo );

   //first frame in each message is the sender identity
   fprintf( fp_clnt_log, "%s : zmq:frame 1\n", time_str );
   zframe_t *identity = zframe_recv( router );
   fprintf( fp_clnt_log, "%s : zmq clnt: checking identity...\n", time_str );
   if (!identity)
   {
       fprintf( fp_clnt_log, "%s : zmq clnt: no identity, breaking.\n", time_str );
       break; //shut down and quit
   }

   fprintf( fp_clnt_log, "%s : zmq:frame 2\n", time_str );
   //second frame is 'fetch' command
   char *command = zstr_recv (router);
   assert (streq (command, "fetch"));
   free (command);

   fprintf( fp_clnt_log, "%s : zmq:frame 3\n", time_str );
   //third frame is chunk offset in file
   char *offset_str = zstr_recv (router);
   size_t offset = atoi (offset_str);
   free (offset_str);

   fprintf( fp_clnt_log, "%s : zmq:frame 4\n", time_str );
   //fourth frame is max chunk size
   char *chunksz_str = zstr_recv (router);
   size_t chunksz = atoi (chunksz_str);
   free (chunksz_str);

   fprintf( fp_clnt_log, "%s : zmq: reading chunk\n", time_str );
   //read chunk of data from file
   fseek (file_to_xfer, offset, SEEK_SET);
   byte *data = malloc (chunksz);
   assert (data);

   fprintf( fp_clnt_log, "%s : zmq: sending chunk\n", time_str );
   //send resulting chunk to client
   size_t size = fread (data, 1, chunksz, file_to_xfer);
   zframe_t *chunk = zframe_new (data, size);
   zframe_send (&identity, router, ZFRAME_MORE);
   zframe_send (&chunk, router, 0);
   //printf("Server: Sending chunk %d\n", chunkNum);
   chunkNum++;
   }

   time( &raw_time );
   timeinfo = localtime( &raw_time );
   time_str = asctime( timeinfo );

   fprintf( fp_clnt_log, "%s : closing file\n", time_str );
   fclose( file_to_xfer );
   fclose( fp_clnt_log );

   return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try checking the value of `errno` or `zmq_errno()` and use with `zmq_strerror()`

From the docs, if socket creation fails then NULL is returned and `errno` will be set to one of the following :

```
EINVAL - requested socket type is invalid.
EFAULT - provided context is invalid.
EMFILE - limit on the total number of open ØMQ sockets has been reached.
ETERM  - context specified was terminated.
```

I'd guess the most likely scenario is that the context passed to send_file is invalid.